# Multiple tab requests

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have a Spring, ibatis application where

1) User will be displayed a list of campaigns

2) User selects a specific campaign and does activities in multiple pages regarding the campaign

3) User opens another tab and selects a different campaign and does some other activities

How do I propagate campaign id in this case? Storing it in session will not work because the campaign id is different in each tab.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should pass the campaignid as a path variable in the url and do different things in different window with the campaignid you get in the pathvariable.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.